# Type.GetType resets logical data in CallContext

Tags: c#, multithreading, log4net, system.reflection, control-flow

```
int c2 = log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Stacks["LDC"].Count;
Type t = Type.GetType(@namespace + entity) ?? Type.GetType(@namespace + entity + postfix);
int c3 = log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Stacks["LDC"].Count;
if (c2 != 0 && c3 == 0) // true
{
    // bp
}
```

`LogicalThreadContext` points to `CallContext.LogicalSetData`.

Why it may happen?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this with log4net 1.2.13 on .NET 4.6.1. You'll need to supply more details, or dig deeper.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I don't know, may be it's reproducable only in certain conditions. I use log4net 1.2.13 too. I have no idea which conditions may affect this behavior. The whole app is pretty big.